# jTokenize(JapaneseTokenize) from jNLP(Japanese Natural Language Processing)

Tags: python

I am trying to tokenize a japanese sentence with jTokenize

```
from jNlp.jTokenize import jTokenize
input_sentence = u'私は彼を５日前、つまりこの前の金曜日に駅で見かけた'
list_of_tokens = jTokenize(input_sentence)
print list_of_tokens
print '--'.join(list_of_tokens).encode('utf-8')
```

There is a syntax error with the print statement in jTokenize.py

I am using python 3.7 which only supports print function "print()"

This jTokenize from jProcessing 0.1 supports python 2.6 and above versions

What would be the solution for this problem.

Comment: Then what is the problem using ```print()```

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when it answers your question. In this way this question does not pop up as unanswered in the searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This jTokenize from jProcessing 0.1 supports python 2.6 and above versions* – do take note that this library code ([Japanese NLP Utilities](https://pypi.org/project/jProcessing/0.1/), `jProcessing 0.1`) is now almost 10 years old and has (almost) not been updated since then (see project on [GitHub](https://github.com/kevincobain2000/jProcessing)).

As such that **library code has not been modernized for Python 3**, and thus may only run on the latest Python 2 release.

Meaning, even if you change `print` (Python 2) to `print(...)` (Python 3) in your example code

```
from jNlp.jTokenize import jTokenize
input_sentence = u'私は彼を５日前、つまりこの前の金曜日に駅で見かけた'
list_of_tokens = jTokenize(input_sentence)
print(list_of_tokens)
print('--'.join(list_of_tokens).encode('utf-8'))
```

and run it with a Python 3 interpreter, you will get Python 3 incompatibility errors from the used library code itself.

So, you have several options:

- Migrate *jProcessing 0.1* from Python 2 to Python 3 ([Differences between Python 2 and 3](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function), see also existing [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kevincobain2000/jProcessing/issues/15)), and then use it with your Python 3 interpreter
- Use *jProcessing 0.1* as is, but downgrade your project to Python 2 (*not a good idea*)
- Find another Python library for *Japanese Natural Language Processing*
- ... bother the maintainers to migrate their library code for Python 3 (see existing [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kevincobain2000/jProcessing/issues/15))

Comment: That would help. Thanks for you suggestions!

Comment: @Manoj Added a link to the already existing GitHub issue; I'm sure they'd happy about a PR from you; should you migrate the code base to Python 3.